# CrystalReports.Net DisplayString function to format bigint string

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports for .Net, we need to remove commas and the decimal places from the string so that only the numeric portion of bigint displays.  We are trying to perform this in the Display String function.

We have tried to use the ToText function but it returns the "Too many arguments passed" error whenever there are two or more arguments supplied.

ToText({table.Field}, 0, '') returns the "too many arguments passed error".

Right now:  The report is displaying the string number as 1,123,456,789.00 and we want it to be 1123456789.  We will also suppress any zero value but we will add that later.

Any ideas how to remove commas and decimal places?

Thanks,
Marty

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution.

Display String function is:
Replace(Replace(CStr({table.field}), ',', ''), '.00', '')

Suppress function is:
CStr({table.field}) = '0' Or CStr({table.field}) = '0.00'

Thanks...